# In JavaScript, how to create an anonymous function with the current value of a variable, at creation and not call time?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, what is the best way to create anonymous function using the ***current*** value of a variable, at the moment the anonymous function is created?

This bogus code for example will use the currentObject value at runtime, when the anonymous function is called. So instead to use objects[i], it uses objects[] (which is absolutely normal).

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < objects.length ; i++) {
    var currentObject = objects[i];
    foo.bind(currentObject.quux, function() {
         bar(currentObject.baz);
    });
}
```

How best to achieve without an eval() this behavior?

Comment: Note: in my production code, I refactored the logic, storing the objects array in a useful variable and creating a more generic anonymous function which takes a parameter matching quux to fetch baz. But I'm interested by the best practices to create anonymous functions matching some constraints.

Comment: The closure monster has claimed its daily victim...

Comment: Joke aside, the "bogus" code you show is a bit too bogus for my taste. Binding `foo` is useless since you don't do anything with the resulting function, and using an array of objects simply adds a layer of complexity that has nothing to do with the problem at hand, which is to define a proper closure for the `bar` invokation. Also there is an extra closing brace in the line before last.

Comment: Some real code would be cool.

Comment: Would have been cool. As answers use the foobar code, it makes sense to keep the question as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual solution is to use an intermediate closure to store your variable :

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < objects.length ; i++) {
    (function(currentObject){
      foo.bind(currentObject.quux, function() {
         bar(currentObject.baz);
      });
    })(objects[i]);
}
```

In the next version of EcmaScript, you'll also be able to use `let` which, contrary to `var`, creates a variable whose scope is the block and not the function call. [The MDN has an example related to your loop problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7#let_definitions).

Comment: let is even supported by IE11+ according http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzt2dkta%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < objects.length ; i++) {
    var currentObject = objects[i];
    foo.bind(currentObject.quux, (function(val) {
         return function() { bar(val); }
    })(currentObject.baz));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < objects.length ; i++) {
    var currentObject = objects[i];
    foo.bind(currentObject.quux, (function(val) {
         return function() {
             bar(val);
         };
    })(currentObject.baz));
}
```